# Update ListView item on click/select

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm new in android and I've got problem with ListView. My ListView loads data from REST service, then using this data ListView is filled. I want to add something lke OnItemClickListener/OnSelectedItemListener on each item and when user cliks on item want to add button. Button should disappear when user clicks on another item. Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**
What have I tried?

1. I've create LinearView which holds ListView and Button
2. ListView is filled in Activity using REST service data (TextView is used for view)
3. I think that my `OnClickListener` class may look like this but I don't know how I can add Button (the best will be create one Button object amd show it only on selected item - I think it will bebetter performance)

   public class RoomClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       Button b = new Button(arg0.getContext());
       b.setText("Join");
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: An OnItemClickListener sound like a good start, what have you tried? Post the your current code and any error you experience.

Comment: Do you need a `Button` for each item or just one for the whole thing?

Comment: I want to create list with TextView's. When user click on TextView then I want to show Button under this TextView but when user click on other TextView then I want to show button under that TextView, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to play with the `android:visibility` of your Button?

Set it to visible/invisible can be a way to do this i guess.

Comment: No I haven't because I think that better will be to add button dynamically. Am I right? Should I add buttons to each of item and shows them onclick?

Comment: I really don't know which solution is the best, but I guess that you can inflate a Button to your selected view. To remove it, set visibility to GONE should do the trick.

Comment: @pepuch What Damien suggest is best. Set the visibility of the button gone in the xml and when an event triggers i.e onItemClick set the visibility of the button visible

Answer (score 0):

Add `button` and call `invalidate()` on the `view` which changed.

This should work.